# I get "unfortunately exchange services has stopped" a few days after setting up exchange email

Tags: email, exchange, motorola-xoom

On my Motorola Xoom running 4.0.3 I can set up an exchange email account and it will work for a day or so then it will give the `"unfortunately exchange services has stopped"` error after checking for new messages (takes a long time to check). I can re-create the account and it will re-download the emails and contacts but then it errors out again soon.

Comment: Are you running a stock ROM or a custom ROM?

Comment: Stock, though it's had official upgrades since we bought it (started at Android 3.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the problem. The user has over 19 thousand emails in his inbox. Moving emails from the inbox to sub folders was all that was needed to fix it.

Comment: If you're still active on Android.SE, don't forget to mark this as an aswer so that it can be marked as solved.